# add new language to /usr/share/dict/words

Tags: password, word-processing

In this directory I have English dict and my language file, but where I can download other language? Or maybe you known other free dictionary? I need to make list of word that are not in the dictionary.

Comment: Your OS/distribution/package manager probably has a few. What are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your Unix, they may be packaged by your system.

For instance, on debian and its derivatives. There's a virtual `wordlist` package provided by different packages like wamerican, wfrench... If you looks at that package in `aptitude`, you'll see the options.

There are also various dictionaries for various spell checker like `ispell` or `myspell` but they might be in different formats. If you look at all the packages that depend on `dictionaries-common` (<kbd>r</kbd> key in `aptitude`), you'll find plenty.